# Error - Returning only 1 value, not searching the array

Tags: c++

I am having trouble getting my code to search an array. No matter what I search, it keeps only returning the cout statement of " Console Not Found". Any suggestions on how to fix this? My program must be in parallel arrays.

```
void lookUpPrice(string name[], float prices[], int size)
{
    string search;
    cout << " Enter Console Name:   ";
    cin >> search; 
    getline(cin, search);

    int index = -1;
    for (int x = 0; x < x; ++x)
    {
        if (name[x] == search)
        {
            index = x; break;
        }
    }
    if (index == -1)
        cout << "Console not found " << endl;
    else
        cout << "The current price for " << search << " $" << setprecision(2) << name[index] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `operator==` for strings is case-sensitive, exact match.

Comment: Hmm, is not also `cin <<` and `getline(cin)` reading search a second time?

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can run your program at your speed and see exactly what the computer does with it as it does it. Typical use is to step through the suspect code line by line keeping an eye out for the program doing something unexpected like storing the wrong value or taking the wrong path. The unexpected is either a mistake in the code or a bad assumption on your part. You'll need to fix either one before continuing.

Answer (score 4):

Your

```
x < x;
```

is NEVER true! Check your condition.

You may want to use

```
for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
```

Comment: Adding `x < size` would not harm.